# How to automate the installation of public and private certificates when deploying build to windows azure?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, security, azure, certificate

My web application uses public and private certificates. I need to host the application in windows azure. How can I automate the installation of public and private certificates on the host server?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use [ServiceManagement API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460799.aspx).  It is REST-based (meaning you can make web-service calls directly) or you can use [csmanage .NET library](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Windows-Azure-CSManage-e3f1882c) 
You will need to have at least one management certificate uploaded, in order to connect to your service via the API.  There are operations to [Add/Remove other certificates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee795178.aspx) within the API